# How do you tell what hard drive a file is on?

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage

On Debian, I have multiple hard drives, how do I know where /var/www is?

Bonus: How do I check the capacity and consumed capacity and of my drives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find where `/var/www` is, by checking where it (or `/var`) is mounted, using the `mount` command.

To check the available/used space on the drives, try `df` (or `df -h` for more readable output). It will show the used and available space in all the mounted partitions. E.g.

```
-> % df -kh
Sist. Arq.       Tam  Usad Dispon. Uso% Montado em
rootfs           94G   34G     60G  36% /
/dev            2,9G     0    2,9G   0% /dev
run             2,9G  484K    2,9G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        94G   34G     60G  36% /
[... the rest was snipped, I have many more partitions ...]
```

Also, `df /path/to/file` works (at least on Linux):

```
-> % df /var/log
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       97667596 34853688  62813908  36% /
```

Comment: Mount won't tell you if any part of the path is a symlink.

Answer (score 11):

You fail to mention your operating system, but on linux, this works:

```
$ df /path/to/some/file/or/directory
Filesystem                          1k-blks    Used   Avail Cap Mounted
/dev/harddisk_partition 8388348 5187768 3200580 62% /home/username
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This is standard behaviour for `df(1)`. It works elsewhere, too.

Comment: Not for HP-UX ;o)

Comment: Right. HP-UX just *has* to be different. (bad memories)

Comment: This will work through symlinks, too. On a Red Hat type box, say `df /etc/grub.conf` and it will probably tell you the disk free space on your `/boot` partition, not on root, where `/etc` probably lives.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mount` to look at your disk mount points.  Look for the longest match for `/var/www` and that's your disk.  In my case, it's `/dev/sda2`.

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ mount
/dev/sda2 on / type ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Drive space consumption in KBytes, per mount point:

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             30759872  22835672   6361680  79% /
tmpfs                  1947664        12   1947652   1% /lib/init/rw
udev                   1943240       104   1943136   1% /dev
tmpfs                  1947664         0   1947664   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              1441280     67136   1300928   5% /boot
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Comment: What do you mean "Look for the longest match for /var/www"

Comment: `/dev/sda2` is mounted on `/`.  That is the longest path that matches `/var/www`.  However, someone below mentioned a better method using `df /var/www`... that will give you the drive mount directly.

Comment: It's also wrong if anything in that path is a symlink.